# Keyframes animation not loading first time page loads (loading as block)

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, transform, breakpoints

I want these two wheels of photos spinning in opposite corners on the homepage for a really simple website. It works when you load it like 2-3 times but there seems to be no rhyme or reason to how how many times it will take and I need it to always work the first. I also can't get my mobile breakpoints to work

I suspected maybe image size was slowing down the animation so I tried linking to photos online inside of to internal files but that didn't seem to work

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.container-text{
    position: fixed;
    top: 3%;
    left: 3%;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    display: flex;
}

.container-bottom-text{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5%;
    text-align: right;
    right: 5%;
    float: right;
    display: flex;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Gothambook;
    src: url(/Gotham-Book.otf);
}

h100 {
    font-family: Gothambook;
    font-size: 20px;
}

h200 {
    font-family: Gothambook;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.container-fluid {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
}

.container-fluid2 {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}

div.animation {
        position: fixed;
        animation: roti 2.5s infinite linear;
        animation-duration: 10s;
}   
  
  
  div.animation2 {
        float: right;
        bottom: 0px;
        animation: rot 2.5s infinite linear;
        animation-duration: 10s;
        animation-delay: -1s;
}  
    
@keyframes rot {
    from {transform:rotate(0deg)
                    translate(300%)
                    rotate(0deg);
                    }
        
    to {transform:rotate(360deg)
                  translate(300%) 
                  rotate(-360deg);
                    }
}

@keyframes roti {
    from {transform:rotate(360deg)
                    translate(-300%)
                    rotate(0deg);
                    }
        
    to {transform:rotate(0deg)
                  translate(-400%) 
                  rotate(360deg);
                    }
}

img {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    width: auto;
    height: 25vw;
    
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 1px) and (max-width : 800px)  {
    
img {
    width: auto;
    height: 95vw;}
    
    h100
    {font-size: 50px;}
    

.container-bottom-text {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5%;
    text-align: right;
    right: 5%;
    float: right;
}

.container-text {
    position: fixed;
    top: 3%;
    left: 3%;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;}

}


img:hover {
  outline: 9px solid #f6e600;
  outline-offset: -4px;
}




</style>
</head>
<body>
    
<div class="container-text">
        <h100>click any pic to enter</h100>
        </div>
        
        <div class="container-bottom-text">
        <h100>for any inquiries please contact <br>scrollingarchives@gmail.com<br> unless it's negative ones then <br>keep that shit to yourself</h100>
        </div>
        
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="animation">
            <a href="" target="first"> <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW16_1.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            
        <div class="animation" style="animation-delay:-1s;">
            <a href="" target="first"> <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW16_2.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            
        <div class="animation" style="animation-delay:-2s;">
            <a href="" target="first"> <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW16_3.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            
        <div class="animation" style="animation-delay:-3s;">
            <a href="" target="first"> <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW16_4.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            
        <div class="animation" style="animation-delay:-4s;">
            <a href="" target="first"> <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW16_5.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            
        <div class="animation" style="animation-delay:-5s;">
            <a href="" target="first"> <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW16_6.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            
        <div class="animation" style=" animation-delay:-6s;">
            <a href="" target="first"> <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW16_7.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            
        <div class="animation" style="animation-delay:-7s;">
            <a href="" target="first"> <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW16_8.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            
             <div class="animation" style="animation-delay:-8s;">
            <a href="" target="first"> <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW16_8.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            
             <div class="animation" style="animation-delay:-9s;">
            <a href="" target="first"> <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW16_8.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            
            </div>
            
          <div class="container-fluid2">  
        <div class="animation" >
            <a href="" target="first"> <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW21_1.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            
        <div class="animation" style="animation-delay:-1s;">
            <a href="" target="first"> <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW21_2.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            
        <div class="animation" style="animation-delay:-2s;">
            <a href="" target="first"> <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW21_3.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            
        <div class="animation" style="animation-delay:-3s;">
            <a href="" target="first"> <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW21_4.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            
        <div class="animation" style="animation-delay:-4s;">
            <a href="" target="first"> <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW21_5.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            
        <div class="animation" style="animation-delay:-5s;">
            <a href="" target="first"> <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW21_6.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            
        <div class="animation" style="animation-delay:-6s;">
            <a href="" target="first"> <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW21_7.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            
        <div class="animation" style="animation-delay:-7s;">
            <a href="" target="first"> <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW21_8.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            
        <div class="animation" style="animation-delay:-8s;">
            <a href="" target="first"> <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW21_9.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            
        <div class="animation" style="animation-delay:-9s;">
            <a href="" target="first"> <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW21_10.jpg"></a>
            </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Based on the provided code snippet, it appears that you're trying to create a simple website with two spinning wheels of photos in opposite corners. If I understood this correctly then I might be able to help.

**1. You talk about prolonged Image loading times.**

- Check the image source paths in your HTML code.
- Try different formatting for .img (e.x.: JPEG or WebP).
- Preload your .img using readily available commands found in CSS/JS to load the mentioned images beforehand.

**2. Animation**

- Sadly your JS, responsible for the animations, is not attached.
- Just make sure that it is properly linked to your HTML.
  - Here you can also use some event listeners 'DOMContentLoaded' or 'window.onload'.

*I. Hope the following makes sense to you (JS not included - Can help you hee too if you require it. Just ask. )*

```js
// JavaScript code for any additional functionality or animation
```

```css
.container-text {
  position: fixed;
  top: 3%;
  left: 3%;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
}

.container-bottom-text {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5%;
  text-align: right;
  right: 5%;
  float: right;
  display: flex;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Gothambook;
  src: url(/Gotham-Book.otf);
}

h100 {
  font-family: Gothambook;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.wheel {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
}

.wheel:nth-child(2) {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: auto;
  right: 10px;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container-text,
  .container-bottom-text {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .wheel {
    position: static;
    margin: 10px auto;
    animation: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-text">
    <!-- Text content here -->
  </div>

  <div class="container-bottom-text">
    <!-- Bottom text content here -->
  </div>

  <div class="wheel"></div>
  <div class="wheel"></div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Regards,

Jonasz